# Extjs creating a context menu on right click

Tags: extjs

I am having trouble with creating context menu(right click). Can someone help me with the code?

My code:

```
var item = RMenu.add({
            text: '$Delete',
            id: 'Delete',
            icon:'../Tce/Images/tcdtpDelete.gif',
            handler:onItemClick,
            tooltip:'$Delete'
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listeners: {
    cellcontextmenu: function(table, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e) {
        Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu',{
            items:[{
                text: 'Delete',
                handler: function() {
                    table.getStore().remove(table.getSelectionModel().getSelection());
                    table.getStore().sync();
                }
            }]
        }).showAt(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably don't want to create a new menu instance on each event, you should cache it in some way.

Comment: It's working well but browser default right-click menu are showing on top. Whats the way to disable browser default right-click menu.

Comment: Then maybe Sencha changed something. You can try whether `e.preventDefault();` works.